# Pythagorean Triangle Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css, pythagorean

I wanted to make a program that can calculate a triangle's missing side using Pythagoras's Theorem. Also the program should draw the triangle to scale either as a svg or on a canvas (It doesn't really matter).
It works for some triangles (like 3,4,5), but others it messes up some lengths (mainly that of side a). Does someone know how to fix this? Please?
[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/Tim-vanH/pen/aLRZrR)

```js
//Following three functions only post the side lengths
function findC(){
  var a = document.getElementById("a1").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b1").value;
  var c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2));
  document.getElementById("outputC").innerHTML="Side A= "+a+ ", Side B= "+b+ ", Side C= "+c;
}

function findB(){
  var a = document.getElementById("a2").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("c2").value;
  var b = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2) -  Math.pow(a, 2));
  document.getElementById("outputB").innerHTML="Side A= "+a+ ", Side B= "+b+ ", Side C= "+c;
}
function findA(){
  var b = document.getElementById("b3").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("c3").value;
  var a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2) -  Math.pow(b, 2));
  document.getElementById("outputA").innerHTML="Side A= "+a+ ", Side B= "+b+ ", Side C= "+c;
}

//Following three functions draw the triangles
function drawSVGC() {
    var a = document.getElementById("a1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b1").value;
    var c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2)); //Calculates sideC
   //To make the drawings larger so that they are visible
    if(a<20){
       a = a*10;
    }
    if(b<20){
      b = b*10;
    }
    if(c<20){
      c = c*10;
    }   
  var x3 = a;
    var y3 = b;
    var ox = 45 - (a / 2);
    var oy = 45 + (y3 / 2);
    var points = [
        [ox, oy].join(','),
        [a + ox, oy].join(','),
        [ox + x3, oy - y3].join(',')
        ].join(' ');
    document.getElementById('triangleC').setAttribute('points', points);
}

var myBtn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
myBtn1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    drawSVGC();
  });

function drawSVGB() {
    var a = document.getElementById("a2").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c2").value;
    var b = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(a, 2)); //Calculates sideB  
    //To make the drawings larger so that they are visible
    if(a<20){
       a = a*10;
    }
    if(b<20){
      b = b*10;
    }
    if(c<20){
      c = c*10;
    }   
  var x3 = a;
    var y3 = b;
    var ox = 45 - (a / 2);
    var oy = 45 + (y3 / 2);
    var points = [
        [ox, oy].join(','),
        [a + ox, oy].join(','),
        [ox + x3, oy - y3].join(',')
        ].join(' ');
    document.getElementById('triangleB').setAttribute('points', points);
}

var myBtn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
myBtn2.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    drawSVGB();
  });

function drawSVGA() {
    var b = document.getElementById("b3").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c3").value;
    var a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(b, 2));//Calculates sideA
    //To make the drawings larger so that they are visible
    if(a<20){
       a = a*10;
    }
    if(b<20){
      b = b*10;
    }
    if(c<20){
      c = c*10;
    }   
  var x3 = a;
    var y3 = b;
    var ox = 45 - (a / 2);
    var oy = 45 + (y3 / 2);
    var points = [
        [ox, oy].join(','),
        [a + ox, oy].join(','),
        [ox + x3, oy - y3].join(',')
        ].join(' ');
    document.getElementById('triangleA').setAttribute('points', points);
}

var myBtn3 = document.getElementById('btn3');
myBtn3.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    drawSVGA();
  });
```

```css
body {
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
 }
div {
    width:380px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    margin:20px auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 20px #666;
    font-size:100;
    text-align:center;
 }
div {
    margin:10px 0;
    float: left;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div>
  <h2>Calculating C</h2>
  <input id="a1" type="number" placeholder="side a"/>
  <input id="b1" type="number" placeholder="side b"/>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="findC()">Find C</button>
  <p id="outputC"></p>
  
  <svg width="200" height="200">
    <polygon id="triangleC"/>
  </svg>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="drawSVGC()">Draw</button>
 </div>
 
 <div>
   <h2>Calculating B</h2>
  <input id="c2" type="number" placeholder="side c"/>
  <input id="a2" type="number" placeholder="side a"/>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="findB()">Find B</button>
  <p id="outputB"></p>
   
  <svg width="200" height="200">
    <polygon id="triangleB"/>
  </svg>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="drawSVGB()">Draw</button>
 </div>
  
  <div>
   <h2>Calculating A</h2>
  <input id="c3" type="number" placeholder="side c"/>
  <input id="b3" type="number" placeholder="side b"/>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="findA()">Find A</button>
  <p id="outputA"></p>
    
  <svg width="200" height="200">
    <polygon id="triangleA"/>
  </svg>
  <button id="btn3" onclick="drawSVGA()">Draw</button>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

[see working demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXygPj)

Before you subtract one side square from other side square you should do it from large one otherwise you are trying to get square root of a minus number which will give you  `NaN` because minus numbers don't have real square roots.you can easily use `Math.abs` to get positive value.and then perform `sqrt` operation.

consider this one

```
 var b = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2) -  Math.pow(a, 2));
```

see you are trying to get root of a minus value if a is large than c

how to fix - use positive value , using Math.abs you can get positive value

```
var b = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(Math.pow(c, 2) -  Math.pow(a, 2))));
```

note: you only need to edit  - related codes,